# Python крестики-нолики с ИИ

Tags: python

Как сделать так, чтобы вместо 2 игрока играл компьютери просто выбирал рандомные пустые места (с объяснением решения если можно)

```
    from random import randint
    
    while True:
        BOARD_SIZE = 3
        board = [i for i in range(9)]
        is_winner = False
        current_player = randint(0, 1)
        markers = {0: 'O', 1: 'X'}
        available_turns = (x for x in range(9))
    
        def draw_board():
            res = ""
            for i, v in enumerate(board):
                res += str(v) + " "
                if (i+1) % BOARD_SIZE == 0:
                     res += "\n"
            print(res)
    
        def validate(value = " "):
            if not value.isdigit() and int(value) not in available_turns:
                raise ValueError ("Enter valid value and try again")
            if board[int(value)] in ('X', 'O'):
                raise ValueError ("This value has already played")
            if '.' in value:
                raise ValueError('Number must be int')
    
        def check_winner():
            current_marker = markers[current_player]
            if board[0] == current_marker and board[4] == current_marker and board[8] == current_marker or \
                    board[2] == current_marker and board[4] == current_marker and board[6] == current_marker or \
                    board[0] == current_marker and board[1] == current_marker and board[2] == current_marker or \
                    board[3] == current_marker and board[4] == current_marker and board[5] == current_marker or \
                    board[6] == current_marker and board[7] == current_marker and board[8] == current_marker or \
                    board[0] == current_marker and board[3] == current_marker and board[6] == current_marker or \
                    board[1] == current_marker and board[4] == current_marker and board[7] == current_marker or \
                    board[2] == current_marker and board[5] == current_marker and board[8] == current_marker:
                return True
            else:
                return False
    
        for i in range(9):
            try:
                input_error = True
                draw_board()
                while input_error:
                    choice = input(f"Player {markers[current_player]} enter your number:\n")
                    validate(choice)
                    input_error = False
                board[int(choice)] = markers[current_player]
                if current_player == 1:
                    
                 #проверить победителя
                is_winner = check_winner()
                if is_winner == True:
                    print(f'Player {markers[current_player]} won the game!!')
                    break
                current_player = 0 if current_player == 1 else 1
                # if is_winner == True:
            except ValueError as ex:
                print(ex)
    
        if is_winner == False:
            print('Draw')
        replay = input("Желаете переиграть? (Y or N)")
        if replay == "Y":
            continue
        else:
            break
```

Comment: это все уже есть на wiki

Comment: Нужно так нужно, делайте.

Answer (score 1):

Делал такого бота. Пусть крестики - игрок, а нолики - ИИ .Смысл таков:(игрок ходит первый)ВЫ должны проверять 3 клетки по горизонтали, вертикали и диагонали. Если там находится два крестика и нету ноликов, то бот должен поставить нолик в той линии, где два крестика чтобы не проиграть. Если нет такой линии (с двумя крестиками), то бот должен строить свою линию ноликов для победы. Он должен найти такую линию, где нету крестиков и ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО с максимальным кол-во ноликов. После того, как он эту линию нашел он должен поставить там нолик. Все это для поля 3х3

Comment: Спасибо, а если просто чтобы компьютер рандомное пустое место выбирал?

Comment: Тогда с ИИ играть будет не интересно. И тгда это уже не бот, который играет как нормальный человек, а обезьяна, которая тыкает куда попало